# Where clause in the Select statement with substring function

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table in the Azure SQL Database like below

[image]

I need to what day is today and compare against the OrderDay field. I was thinking I could do something like below in the where clause

```
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday,GETDATE()), 0, 4)
```

There are is an issue with it when I added this in the select

[image]

Though I am running it today where I am still in the CST timezone its still Monday here and the Azure DB is located in EAST US but it is returning Tue.

Comment: I assume it's returning for UTC. Could you subtract 5 hours from current_timestamp and finagle to date? Or this looks to be a good writeup on it https://blog.greglow.com/2020/03/12/sql-getting-local-date-and-time-in-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure SQL Database always follows **UTC** time zone.

Use [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to convert it to **CST** or another **non-UTC** time zone.

Use the below syntax to get the day information in the CST time zone using AT TIME ZONE

`SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday,getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'), 0, 4)`

[image]

> You can also refer **sys.time_zone_info** **view** to check **current utc offset** information.

`select * from sys.time_zone_info`

[image]